# Ubuntu Server setup: How to install Ubuntu on one drive and use other drive for file storage?

Tags: server, hard-drive, software-installation, raid, ssd

I've built a computer to use as a home file server. I will be installing Ubuntu Server. I've put a small SSD and two large HDDs in it. I have no prior experience with Ubuntu (desktop or server). I've watched several videos that walkthrough the server installation and setup process and I've read lots of tutorials explaining it. I'm confident I can get it setup and configured but I want to install the Ubuntu server on the SSD and then use the two HDDs for file storage, preferably in RAID 1.

So how do I set it up so that the OS is on the SSD and all the files are on the HDDs? All the videos/tutorials I've watched/read have just used one drive for the OS AND the file storage.

Any helpful instructions or links would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you have two devices

```
/dev/sda - will be ssd
/dev/sdb - will be hdd
```

in **sda** you create new partition ext4 with mount point **/**, and for    **sdb** - you create ext4 with mount point **/home**

And in the future you put all your files in home/user directory

Comment: Thanks. So I just select the SSD during installation and worry about creating the partitions and directories on the other drives afterwards when I'm configuring samba and whatever else?

Comment: yes, you can create this another partitions after installing OS.

I would recommend for beginners webmin for ease administration of ubuntu server.

Comment: also after webmin installing to ubuntu server, i can try to search "webmin create linux raid" for additional hdd drivers.